# Как использовать spring webflux,

Tags: java, spring

мне нужно только для двух добавления двух сервисов, который не будет меняться в дальнейшем, читаю и  вижу два варианта без spring boot и со спрингом. какой лучше использовать, Еще вопрос про GetMapping, действительно ли он асинхронно будет отдавать ответы?

Comment: Изучите документацию и вопросы отпадут сами собой

Comment: чтобы у вас приложение было асинхронным, у вас должны все классы быть асинхронными, начиная от контроллера и закнчивая драйвером базы.

Comment: @gencloud да читал, но остались вопросы но не сильно понял какая разница будет при и без использования spring

Comment: @aleshka-batman да это я понимаю

Comment: @aleshka-batman webflux контроллеры выполняет в eventloop'е Netty с использованием EventExecutorGroup, так что вызывать блокирующие операции можно, но лучше не злоупотреблять.

Comment: Из вашего вопроса непонятны ни требования к вашему приложения, ни варианты, которые вы видите.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev это понятно, но дело в том, что синхронные операции полностью блочат поток и новые реквесты не обрабатываются/откладываются.

Comment: @aleshka-batman `EventExecutorGroup` как раз пул потоков использует. Главное его не исчерпать.